# Context path on Apache reverse proxy for multiple backend services

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

I have a setup for an apache reverse proxy for multiple applications as below:

```
https://serverxx:8000 -> http://localhost:9000
https://serverxx:8001 -> http://localhost:9001
https://serverxx:8002 -> http://localhost:9002
```

There are 3 virtual hosts files under /etc/httpd/conf.d/ which accomplishes this setup, and they look like the following:

```
Listen 8000 https

<VirtualHost *:8000>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyRequests     Off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"

    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

    ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:9000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Due to new requirements, there needs to be some overhaul. The 3 applications which are accessible via https://serverxx:800[0,1,2] should now look like this:

```
https://serverxx/app1 -> http://localhost:9000
https://serverxx/app2 -> http://localhost:9001
https://serverxx/app3 -> http://localhost:9002
```

In other words, serverxx will only be listening on 1 port (443) and have 3 different context paths for 3 different proxied services.

Is this possible at all? I have been reading on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html but couldn't get a definite answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured this out.

For those who are interested with an answer, the key is to add multiple ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse values for each context path pointing to multiple backend servers.

```
Listen 8000 https

<VirtualHost *:8000>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyRequests     Off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"

    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

    ProxyPass         /app1 -> http://localhost:9000
    ProxyPassReverse  /app1 -> http://localhost:9000

    ProxyPass         /app2 -> http://localhost:9001
    ProxyPassReverse  /app2 -> http://localhost:9001

    ProxyPass         /app3 -> http://localhost:9002
    ProxyPassReverse  /app3 -> http://localhost:9002

</VirtualHost>
```